# Make scaled-down image on HTML page clickable to see it in full size

Tags: html, image, zooming, clickable

I'm recoding a website to make it responsive. For images, I'm using a CSS rule like `img {max-wdith: 100%}`. But if an image is scaled-down, I'd like to make it clickable so the visitor can open the full size version if required.

Can anyone recommend a good and robust solution for that (a jQuery plugin, etc)?

It would be nice if it were a smart wrapper for the classic HTML `<img>` tag to be SEO-friendly.

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Comment: @SebastianWąsik, how is it related to my question? As I know, all images wrapped with fancyBox, are clickable - even if they are full-sized. Or am I wrong?